# How to put a random.shuffle(string) inbetween print message?

Tags: python

So currently my code is

```
print("   1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8")
print(game_string + "|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")
print("|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")
```

and when I run it, it becomes

```
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
% % %|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
```

(Separated into 3 lines of course)
I'm wanting it to become | % | | % | | | etc, with the %'s being in random places each time I run the code.

The code I used to make the shuffled list:

```
import random

l = list(" % % % ")

random.shuffle(l)

s = ''.join(l)
```

Comment: Do you know what the command `print()` does that you are using as stated above? Please be more precise on what you want to achieve and why your code does not yield the desired result.

Comment: Once I run the code print(game_string + "| | | |") it comes out as %% % | | | | while I want it to come out as | % | % | etc so the shuffled/random string goes inbetween the " | | ". I understand why this happens but how can I fix it. Do I need to add more code to make it run the way I want it to? Hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Please check my extended answer. In case you have more questions, please consider opening up a new one. If one the answers resolves your issue, please `accept` it to mark this question as resolved at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this problem a bit differently, ***separating the presentation from data***.

**Implementation**

```
def foo(n):
    import random
    game_string = list('%%%' + ' '*(n-3))

    yield ' '.join(map(str,range(1,n + 1)))
    while True:
        random.shuffle(game_string)
        yield '|'.join(game_string)
```

**Demo**

```
>>> for _, row in zip(range(5), foo(10)):
    print row


1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 | |%|%| | | |%| | 
 |%| | | | |%|%| | 
 | |%| | | |%| |%| 
 | |%| |%| | |%| |
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not shuffling the string that includes *all* characters of interest. Here is one example for an approach you may take:

```
#import packages
import random

#create list of all characters that are to be mixed up
l = list("%%%|||||||||")
#do shuffle
random.shuffle(l)
#output shuffled list to console
print( ''.join(l) )
```

This will print difference sequences every time you shuffle the list.

Instead of printing the shuffled string to the screen, you could store it in your variable, e.g.

```
game_string = ''.join(l)
```

Note that

```
print(game_string + "|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")
```

will simply print two concatenated strings, namely the content of the variable `game_string` and the given string. There is no shuffling involved here. You may want to look up *string concatenation using python* to learn more about this, e.g. at http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to say that the lines are fixed. So it has to look like this (with random "%" or " " between the lines)
   1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
|      |  %  |      |     |  %   |     |  %   |     |
|      |       |      |     |        |     |        |     |